# One-hot encoding multi-level column data

Tags: python, pandas, encoding

I have the following data frame where there are records with features about different subjects:

```
ID   Feature
-------------------------
1    A
1    B
2    A
1    A
3    B
3    B
1    C
2    C
3    D
```

I'd like to get another (aggregated?) data frame where each row represents a specific subject, and there are an exhaustive list of all one-hot encoded features:

```
ID   FEATURE_A FEATURE_B FEATURE_C FEATURE D
--------------------------------------------
1    1         1         1         0
2    1         0         1         0
3    0         1         0         0
```

How could it be implemented in Python (Pandas)?

Bonus: how could be implemented a version where the feature columns contain occurence numbers, not just binary flags?

Answer (score 9):

Use [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html), then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and aggregate `max`:

```
df =df[['ID']].join(pd.get_dummies(df['Feature']).add_prefix('FEATURE_')).groupby('ID').max()
print (df)
    FEATURE_A  FEATURE_B  FEATURE_C  FEATURE_D
ID                                            
1           1          1          1          0
2           1          0          1          0
3           0          1          0          1
```

Detail:

```
print (pd.get_dummies(df['Feature']))
   A  B  C  D
0  1  0  0  0
1  0  1  0  0
2  1  0  0  0
3  1  0  0  0
4  0  1  0  0
5  0  1  0  0
6  0  0  1  0
7  0  0  1  0
8  0  0  0  1
```

Another solution with [MultiLabelBinarizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html) and `DataFrame` constructor:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
df1 = pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df['Feature']),
                   columns=['FEATURE_' + x for x in mlb.classes_], 
                   index=df.ID).max(level=0)
print (df1)
    FEATURE_A  FEATURE_B  FEATURE_C  FEATURE_D
ID                                            
1           1          1          1          0
2           1          0          1          0
3           0          1          0          1
```

**Timings**:

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 100000
L = list('abcdefghijklmno'.upper()) 
df = pd.DataFrame({'Feature': np.random.choice(L, N),
                   'ID':np.random.randint(10000,size=N)})

def jez(df):
    mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
    return pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df['Feature']),
                   columns=['FEATURE_' + x for x in mlb.classes_], 
                   index=df.ID).max(level=0)


#jez1
In [464]: %timeit (df[['ID']].join(pd.get_dummies(df['Feature']).add_prefix('FEATURE_')).groupby('ID').max())
10 loops, best of 3: 39.3 ms per loop

In [465]: %timeit (jez(df))
10 loops, best of 3: 138 ms per loop

#Scott Boston1
In [466]: %timeit (df.set_index('ID')['Feature'].str.get_dummies().add_prefix('FEATURE_').max(level=0))
1 loop, best of 3: 1.03 s per loop

#wen1
In [467]: %timeit (pd.crosstab(df.ID,df.Feature).gt(0).astype(int).add_prefix('FEATURE '))
1 loop, best of 3: 383 ms per loop

#wen2
In [468]: %timeit (pd.get_dummies(df.drop_duplicates().set_index('ID')).sum(level=0))
10 loops, best of 3: 47 ms per loop
```

#### Caveat

The results do not address performance given the proportion of `Feature` and `ID`, which will affect timings a lot for some of these solutions.

Answer (score 4):

Another similiar option is to use `set_index`, `.str` (string accessor), `get_dummies` and `max` with `level=0` parameter, then use `add_prefix` to change column names:

```
df.set_index('ID')['Feature'].str.get_dummies().add_prefix('FEATURE_').max(level=0)
```

Output:

```
    FEATURE_A  FEATURE_B  FEATURE_C  FEATURE_D
ID                                            
1           1          1          1          0
2           1          0          1          0
3           0          1          0          1
```

Answer (score 4):

By using `pd.crosstab`

```
pd.crosstab(df.ID,df.Feature).gt(0).astype(int).add_prefix('FEATURE ')
Out[805]: 
Feature  FEATURE A  FEATURE B  FEATURE C  FEATURE D
ID                                                 
1                1          1          1          0
2                1          0          1          0
3                0          1          0          1
```

Or using `drop_duplicates` then `get_dummies`

```
pd.get_dummies(df.drop_duplicates().set_index('ID')).sum(level=0)
Out[808]: 
    Feature_A  Feature_B  Feature_C  Feature_D
ID                                            
1           1          1          1          0
2           1          0          1          0
3           0          1          0          1
```

---

Additional Answer : ***how could be implemented a version where the feature columns contain occurence numbers, not just binary flags?***

Option1

```
pd.crosstab(df.ID,df.Feature)
Out[809]: 
Feature  A  B  C  D
ID                 
1        2  1  1  0
2        1  0  1  0
3        0  2  0  1
```

Or

Option 2

```
pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('ID')).sum(level=0)
```